# Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.h2.console.enabled'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, h2

When I try to set the `spring.h2.console.enabled` to `true` in my `application.properties` file, I'm getting a Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.h2.console.enabled' error.

This is how the dependencies in my pom.xml file look like

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.210</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have tried restarting Intellij and updating the project but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you display your `application.properties` file?

Comment: I have the same issue. Here's my application.properties  @HarryCoder `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./h2 databases/mdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.sql.init.mode=always

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
`

Comment: Which release of Spring Boot are you using? Auto-configuration of H2 console was temporarily dropped in the milestone release 3.0.0-M1 but reinstated in 3.0.0-M2.